# Google Chart Gauge with multiple color zones

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, gauge

I'm using **Google Charts API** to create a gauge chart. It is a very simple and effective API to create charts on-the-fly.

Here is the documentation for that chart

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge

Now, I need to customize a litte bit this chart adding more than a green zone. 
For example I need a green zone that goes from 0 to 10, one from 20 to 30 and another from 40 to 50, but it doesn't seems possible.

Here is the options to pass to the **draw()** method for setting up the green zone

```
var options = {          
greenFrom: 0, greenTo: 10          
};
```

I tried to pass an array as an option, but it obviously doesn't works. Here is what I tried.

```
var options = {          
greenFrom: [0, 20, 40], greenTo: [10, 30, 50]
};
```

Has anyone got the same problem?

Any help is appeciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it, just override the colors for the red and yellow zones as well. If you want those too though then you are out of luck.

```
var options = {
   greenFrom: 0,
   greenTo: 10,
   greenColor: "#00ff00",
   redFrom: 20,
   redTo: 30,
   redColor: "#00ff00",
   yellowFrom: 40,
   yellowTo: 50,
   yellowColor: "#00ff00"
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was my first solution, but now I need 4 or more areas and that hack doesn't works.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately you can't do that with gauges in Google Charts ([relevant discussion on google forums](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-visualization-api/Z6ghp0rsjM0/discussion)). There are other open source javascript gauges out there though

Comment: Also you can try Perfect Widgets: http://perfectwidgets.com. They allows to create full customizable gauges by assembling them from the parts.

Comment: Can we put 4 colors in options like green,yellow, red and blue..?